# When I save() the "App\Post" returns the 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Well, i got some very strange error, this very simple code returns the **500 error.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CommentController extends Controller
{

   public function NewComment(Request $request) {
     $cText = $request->commentText;

     $comment = new Comment;
     $comment->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $comment->current_text = $cText;
     $comment->save();
     return $comment;
    }
[...]
}
```

When I comment the **$comment->save();** Returns:

```
  author_id: 1
  current_text: "fsdfdfd"
```

OBS: "fsdfdfd" is the text I typed in the **<'textarea'>** in the page.

As you can see returns the object normally, but when I try to save returns the error:

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

> Migration file of the Comments:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('author_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('current_text')->nullable(false);
        $table->enum('edited', ['yes','no'])->default('no');
        $table->string('history', 8000);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

> Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'author_id',
      'current_text',
      'edited',
      'history'];

    protected $guarded = [
      'updated_at',
      'created_at'];

    function author(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check laravel.log file of project? may be that will give you some detail level error message.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with the error you are getting, but the `users()` relationship is not correct. First of all, it should be named `user` or `author`, singular. Secondly, you don't have a `user_id` field but a `author_id`, so you need to specify that: `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse.

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log` will tell you exactly what happened.

Comment: Please show the detail of 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found what was wrong!!**

The error was before any of those scripts, was in the AJAX function.
The object that was sending the data, was something like this:

```
var objectComment = {
  'commentText': textComment
};
```

Because of it, I was getting a json like this in my php file:

```
{'commentText : Lorem ipsun' : null}
```

And was trying to get some value through this... #facepalm

Other thing that was wrong, is that i forget to configure the CSRF Token, it was disturbing the data sending and helping to drive me crazy a little more.

Hope I could help some of you with this error caused by a little daydream :)